# Event scheduler of mysql should not work on a particular month

Tags: mysql

I have an event scheduler, called 'MonthlySal', which will work on the first day of every month at 12:01 AM (That is at mid-night). But the same event should not work on some specified months.

Example: On April event, 'MonthlySal', should not work on April.

```
CREATE EVENT MonthlySal
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2011-01-01 00:02:00' + interval 0 minute
DO
call updateSal();
```

And I thought of keep a conditional statement, that is IF MONTH IS NOT APRIL THEN execute the body of event. Is this right way?

That is,

```
CREATE EVENT MonthlySal
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2011-01-01 00:02:00' + interval 0 minute
DO
BEGIN
    IF month(curdate()) == 'APRIL' THEN  -- roughly I have written
        call updateSal();
    END IF
END
```

Please could any one suggest me the proper way to resolve this.

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: I thought of keep a conditional statement, that is IF MONTH IS NOT APRIL THEN execute the body of event.

Comment: Are there anybody else other than  Fahim Parkar, Devart. I don't know what happened to these two guys. They have to react only when they know something, if not they have to wait some one else to answer, and increase their knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL there is no way to create an event that will work not in interval, but on given conditions, like crontab can. So there is no particular way to exclude a certain month from every-month interval.

An approach in which, in code, one can exclude an execution of the procedure is the correct one. The other would be to schedule the same procedure (event) for every month that one needs to. But that will create a lot of events in the future and will, for sure, prove hard to be maintained if any changes will be necessary.

So, an in-code approach would be:

```
CREATE EVENT e_salary
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS '2012-03-01 00:00:00'
    COMMENT 'My event to do something with salaries'
    DO
      CALL updateSal();
```

**and** in `updateSal()` I suggest adding

```
IF (MONTH(CURDATE()) = 4)
THEN
  //some code you already have
END IF;
```

My proposal is to add the logic in the procedure rather then in the event comes from the simple fact the condition on when to execute this logic is tightly tied to the logic itself, not the event. The event is merely a *scheduled executor* and it should not have excessive logic of it's own. It will simplify the design of the job as far as you will keep all the logic and run conditions in one place. Additionally you can extend that condition to, for example, use a table which will be edited by your application, thus providing a possibility for administrator to change the condition without modifying MySQL definitions.

Comment: ok.. But shall I following logic (alternative).  IF month(curdate()) == 'APRIL' THEN -- roughly I have writtn call updateSal(); END IF END